# restrict user access to controller based on property in object (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to control user access to a controller. I have local User object with a property(boolean - "IsSubscribed"). Users can only access the controller if the value is true.

Notes:

I use forms authentication, but NO .net membership/profile etc.

mvc version 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom [Authroize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            // Perform your custom authorization and return true/false
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

and then decorate your controller/actions with this attribute.

Comment: 1.So do we go like

[Authorize(...)]
public ActionResult myAction()

(or)

[CustomAuthorize(...)]
public ActionResult myAction()

Comment: @maxxxee, `[CustomAuthorize] public ActionResult MyAction() { ... }`